# Report request instance's results before request class is instanced

Tags: python, flask

I have such a view function to handle Forms, within it, I set a `print(request.form) to test the request instance.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    print(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))
```

Then the server report the result:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', 'IjUwYjVlYTRiMzk5OTNiMjg1MGE3NjhiOWI2YjUwOTVjMmI5ODMyNmYi.XfBlbA.gSdMwVqFwhkaycx-y6v_r-GBNhQ'), ('name', 'test'), ('submit', 'Submit')])
```

I am little confused about the request here.

`request` class is import by `from flask import request`, however, the class has not been instanced before it get to work.

The server get the result from `print(request.form)`, but the request is not instanced in any corner of the view script file.

If request has already instanced globally, then remove `from flask import request`, print(request) would report nameError.

So the flask read the header of imports firstly then instanced it in other places?

Answer (score 1):

When the Flask application receives a request, it needs to make a few objects available to the view functions that will handle it. A simple example of this query params from the request or some form data. One way in which Flask could give a view function access to the request object is by sending it as an argument, another way could be making some globally accessible objects. To avoid cluttering view functions with lots of arguments that may or may not be needed, Flask uses contexts to temporarily make certain objects globally accessible. The `current_app, g, request, and session` proxies are available to the original thread handling the request. For more details look at the documentation here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/.

Comment: yes, but if you not `from flask import request`, the global request is not accessible.

Comment: Import is necessary if you want to access the request context. Flask internally handles the request object intialization and other things.